# Changing directory of logs

Tags: logs, rsyslog

I'm trying to configure a central syslog server running rsyslog. I've set up the configuration so that it is capturing the firewall logs from our Cisco router.

We have an NFS share attached to the syslog server, I'd like to store the logs here but everytime I try and set it as the store location for the logs I stop receiving the logs from the router. Is it possibly to use another directory other than /var/log to store logs?

Comment: 1) have you configured it on rsyslog configuration file ? 2) is write-by-root access allowed on NFS server ? (you may need spacial setup for latter case)

Comment: Try running with debug, `sudo rsyslogd -dn` to see if it provides any messages. Add the relevant lines from your nfs exports, and the syslog config to your post if you want better answers.

Comment: Did you  set permissions on the new directory correctly?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to set up a cron job (or systemd.timer) to rsync everything in `/var/log/` to the NFS share at regular intervals.

That way, you'll also have an extra set of logs, in case the log server or NFS share go down for some reason.

Comment: I think its not a smart solution and not an answer to the question. What if the logs are heavy? Then they would occupy double the space on system.

Comment: It is a simple solution that provides redundancy. The files will not occupy double space on the machine, since the copy is sent to another server, as per the question. If the logs are heavy, then rsync has an update option that skips existing/older files, making only the first run heavy.